# XeLaTeX complaining about fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, moderncv, moderntimeline

I have TeXLive 2011 installed.

My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\tlmaxdates{2000}{2013}
\tlwidth{0.8ex}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
%\title{}
\address{street}{postcode city}
\mobile{+4~(11)~311~111}
%\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mail@yahoo.com}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional info}·
% '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of
% the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of
% the picture file.
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture.png}
%\quote{}

\begin{document}

%\setmainfont[
%  Extension=.otf,
%  UprightFont=*-Regular,
%  BoldFont=*-Bold,
%  ItalicFont=*-It,
%  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt,
%]{MinionPro}
%\setsansfont[
%  Extension=.otf,
%  UprightFont=*-Regular,
%  BoldFont=*-Bold,
%  ItalicFont=*-It,
%  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt,
%]{MyriadPro}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}

\section{Expirience}

\subsection{Other}
\tlcventry[orange]{2001}{0}{Administration}{COMPANY}{City}{}{Short Description%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Item One 
\begin{itemize}%
  \item Item Two 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}}

\section{Foreign Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent}{Some description here}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this, I'm getting a warning like this:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/MyriadPro(0)/m/n' instead on input line 58.
```

And in `\tlcventry` "COMPANY" is not italicized (I mean it should be treated like text with `\textit` or `\emph` - by default `\tlcventry` makes field `#4` italicized).

A little preview of how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Bug in `fontspec` not defining an `sl` shape (regression though, this used to word), fixed in the repository a while ago, but not uploaded to CTAN yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Myriad Pro font doesn't have a slanted form and `fontspec` seems not to be able to substitute italic automatically, so you can help it by saying

```
\setsansfont[SlantedFont=* Italic]{Myriad Pro}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that, egreg. Didn't know about this. Now output seems to be as elegant as it can only be.

Comment: @Teddy I've discovered it because of your question. :) Please read the FAQ about what to do when an answer solves your problem.